# Dependencies in Monorepo

Tags: javascript, monorepo

In a monorepo, if you have a dependency in one package can you use that dependency in another package without adding it to that package? For more clarity, check the below layout.

```
Project
   |-packages
       |- packageA
            |- package.json (Here let say I have lodash dependency)
            |- index.js
       |- packageB
            |-package.json (I haven't added lodash here.)
            |- index.js
```

So, can I import lodash in packageB's index.js or do I have to add it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `packageB` use lodash, you should list lodash in the `package.json` file of `packageB`. If you don't, bad things could happen. For example, consider the following situations:

1. lodash is removed from `packageA`. In your case, you mentioned that `packageA` lists lodash as a dependency. However, if down the road you refactored `packageA` where it no longer needs lodash, you might remove it thinking that it is unused. If `packageB` was relying on `packageA` installing lodash, then `packageB` would break due to the missing dependency.
2. `packageB` is installed without `packageA`. Without knowing what your packages contain it's hard to know for sure, but it is possible that now or down the road you (or someone else) could install `packageB` without installing `packageA`. You would then wind up with the same situation where lodash is not installed and `packageB` would break.
3. `packageA` updates to a new major version of lodash. If `packageB` is no longer compatible with the new major version of lodash, it could break. This would not be a problem if `packageB` specified it's own dependency on lodash as you could update them together or separately depending on what is best.

Other situations could happen, these are just a few examples.

Note, you *could* specify lodash as a peer dependency in both `packageA` and `packageB` letting the consuming application install lodash so you don't have to install it in both packages, but that doesn't really simplify things either in your monorepo or in your consuming applications.

Answer (score 0):

As being different packages, you have to you the dependency in both. You can use [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) for monorepo to match dependencies and assign as root dependecy.

```
lerna link convert
```

Comment: And does it apply for peerDependencies as well?

Comment: Needs to be specified as devDependencies too. [Source](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/375)